# Managing Lambda handler Credentials in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

My Aws Lambda function is written in Java. I am getting data from DynamoDb by giving some static credentials like below;

```
new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESSKEY, SECRETKEY)
```

However, when i try to define my services in Aws Cloudformation. I could not find any way, how can i change these accesskey and secretkey credentials. What is the best way for managing these credentials?, Because they are special keys for each account and embedded in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use the context or download a file to pass credentials in runtime, one should not use explicit hard-coded credentials, as that is harder to acquire and rotate securely.

It is easier and safer to use roles, as described in the lambda permission model: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html

Use explicit credentials only outside AWS (your dev machine for example), and even so do not hard-code them, use environment variables or CLI profiles.